# Java Code Design Using ExecutorService That Calling Mutliple Services

Tags: java, executorservice

I am attempting to run 15 services parallely and each service will send mail to different set of customers. Extraction criteria will differ from every services

**Service1, Service2, Service3.... Service15**. Each class extends **NotificationService** class.

NotificationService class have methods extractRecipients(), sendMail(), sendSMS(), logNotification().

**All Service classes[1 to 15]** have process() method that will call **NotificationService** methods and do their job.

is this correct way to design the java code?

**And below code looks ugly, is there any smart way to handle. Please someone help me.**

```
public void startService() {

try {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    for (;;) {
        service.submit(new Service1(conn) {
                    public Object call(){
                        try {
                            process(conn, param2); // Passing connection & obj
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw e;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });

        service.submit(new Service2(conn) {
                    public Object call(){
                        try {
                            process(conn, param2);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw e;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });

        // like above i have 15 services. so its ugly.
    }

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public boolean process(Connection conn) throws Exception {
try {
// getRecipientsList(serviceID);

// sendMail(recipientsList);

// logNotificationDetails(notificationList);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
}
```

Comment: Why have different services when you have same task(email) to perform?

Comment: 15 emails?  To the same customer?  How annoying.  I'd suggest using some logic to combine them.  I'd also separate the service operation from sending email.  Make that a separate step.  They should not extend NotifyingService.

Comment: Every service class[Service1-15] will call their own sql and extract the recipients. So 15 sub class and one parent class..

Comment: for reusabilty, i wrote methods like extractRecipients(), sendMail(), sendSMS(), logNotification(). because it is common to all services.

Comment: 15 emails are not sending to the same customer. eg. different customer have different extraction criterias. extraction criteria will differ from every service class.

Comment: @duffymo Is there any solution for above code, its looks ugly. Because 15 services call by ExecutorService at a same time.

Comment: Why don't you have NotificationService implement Callable? Implementations seem identical.

Comment: @Fildor i have public class Service1 extends NotificationService implements Callable<Object>

Comment: Then you are using an endless loop to submit One-Shot Tasks. Why not use Scheduled Executor and schedule them recurring?

Comment: "i have public class Service1 extends NotificationService implements Callable<Object>" Yes - but you implement Callable in place. Why not shift that code to NotificationService.java ? It seems that all ServiceN classes share the same implementation.

Comment: This job will execute for every minute. so i put infinite loop. sorry i don't know to use Scheduled Executor

Comment: "This job will execute for every minute." So inside `process` you check if one minute has passed since last execution? See ScheduledExecutorService docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html You could use [scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1 TimeUnit.MINUTES)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

Comment: No i will check inside startService() to run for every minute.

Comment: And when do you stop? And how? `startService` will hang in the loop forever blocking its caller.

Comment: "Why not shift that code to NotificationService.java ? It seems that all ServiceN classes share the same implementation" - Because in startService() i am passing different paramters. and i should execute 15 services parallely.

Comment: So? `process` still uses the instance vars `param2` and `conn` - if they are of the same type for each ServiceN then you can move that code. And in fact, I think you *should*. Is `process` an abstract method in `NotificationService` ?

Comment: Have you actually tested this code?

Comment: startService loop will run every minute, in every minute 15 service will run parallely and send notification.

Comment: Yes Fildor i tested and it is same type. I agreed your point to move process to NotificationService and ignore Service1,Service2 classes.... but in start service how to handle this 15 service.

Comment: No, it won't. 3 services will run parallely. All 15 will be executed over and over again, though. And every minute this will get worse.

Comment: Fildor Sorry, can you please say me how to handle this 15 service in above startService() method. Here param2 is bean and contains serviceID,service email subject,body and all

Comment: Well, as a starter, you can get rid of the `for(;;)` and shutdown the executor at the end. I guess that will already improve behavior if you insist on using that `startService` method being called every minute.

Comment: Also see my answer for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points for improvement (not complete):

I am assuming that Service1, Service2, ... classes are derived from NotificationService, overriding the `process` method.

**anonymous interface implementation** of `Callable<Object>`:

```
service.submit(new Service1(conn) {
                public Object call(){
                    try {
                        process(conn, param2); // Passing connection & obj
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw e;
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });
```

should be moved to NotificationService class. This code then reduces to:

```
service.submit(new Service1(conn)); // Will call Service1's "process" implementation
service.submit(new Service2(conn)); // Will call Service2's "process" implementation
...
```

**Edit:**

What I have in mind is this setup:

```
abstract class NotificationService implements Callable<Object>{
  // ...

  // I don't know what types conn and param2 are, so ...
  protected abstract void process( ConnType conn, Param2Type param2 );

  @Override
  public Object call(){
      try {
              process(conn, param2); // Passing connection & obj
      } catch (Exception e) {
              throw e;
      }
      return null;
  }
}
```

You then can override `process` in Service1, Service2 ... to handle the process in their specific way.

```
class Service1 extends NotificationService{
    @Override
    protected void process( ConnType conn, Param2Type param2 ){
        // do process according to Service1's needs.
    }
}
```

---

**Endless loop:**

```
for(;;){
   service.submit(...
}
```

will block the caller of `startService` in that loop while new Tasks are added to the Executor **forever**.

If each execution leads to an email to the customer, he will already be flooded.

---

**Calling `startService` every minute:**

will result in a **new ExecutorService** that will **be endlessly flooded** with tasks every minute!

This will not only spam your customers but should also degrade performance pretty fast.

---

*For a starter*, you could change like so:

```
public void startService() {

try {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);


        service.submit(new Service1(conn)); // assuming callable impl is moved

        service.submit(new Service2(conn));

        // like above i have 15 services. so its ugly.
    service.shutdown();

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

---

An alternative would be to use *one* ScheduledExecutorService on which you schedule each Service*N* to be executed every minute.

Comment: You saying that callable impl should be move to process method and process method should be in NotificationService.

Comment: No. `call()` should be in NotificationService. Your ServiceN classes still need to override the process method to have different implementations.

Comment: Fildor, Please see my below answer. this will OK right.

Comment: Ok Fildor, Then my old code is same as that you are saying. I have call and process method inside ServiceN classes and passing param new Service1(conn, param2)

Comment: Fildor, Please see my process method above.

Comment: @Siva see my edit. I hope that will make it clearer.

Comment: Fildor, How to pass param2 to process(conn, param2). i can get param2 in startService() method.

Comment: I don't know where param2 is declared, so it's hard for me to tell. If it is a protected field in NotificationService, then you can access it directly in the ServiceN classes. I guess you'd want to do it just like `conn`.

Comment: Ok Fildor,  I can get param2 in startService() method.
Then conn & param2  in every ServiceN classes constructor instead of paramteres in process( ConnType conn, Param2Type param2 ), am i right.

Comment: Thank you so much Fildor. Your mentoring is superb. Thanks for your time spent for this and i am really happy for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use invokeAll of executor service.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void startService() {

try {
    List<Bean> list = getServicesNotificationList();

    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(list.size); here list size should be 15

    for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        service.submit(new NotificationService(conn, list[i]));
    }

    service.shutdown();

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```